# Java 9 error: not in a module on the module source path

Tags: java, compiler-errors, java-9, java-module, module-path

### Project structure

I have a project written in Java 8 and I want to update it to Java 9. So I separated the classes into 2 separate modules. Modules:

- `org.ggp.base` with `module-info.java` in the directory `org.ggp.base/src/main/java`. Its build was automated with Gradle before I started the update to Java 9. The module uses an abstract class implementation included in `pl.edu.prz.klopusz` module.
- `pl.edu.prz.klopusz` in the directory `pl.edu.prz.klopusz/dolar-app/src/main/java`. I want to automate its build using Maven. The module requires `org.ggp.base` module.

The file tree looks like:

```
.
├── org.ggp.base/
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src/
│       └── main/
│           ├── java/
│           │   ├── external/
│           │   │   └── JSON/
│           │   │       ├── JSONArray.java
│           │   │       └── JSONObject.java
│           │   ├── META-INF/
│           │   │   └── MANIFEST.MF
│           │   ├── module-info.java
│           │   └── org/
│           │       └── ggp/
│           │           └── base/
│           │               └── util/
│           │                   ├── statemachine/
│           │                   │   ├── MachineState.java
│           │                   │   └── StateMachine.java
│           │                   └── symbol/
│           └── resources/
│               └── org/
│                   └── ggp/
│                       └── base/
└── pl.edu.prz.klopusz/
    └── dolar-app/
        └── src/
            └── main/
                └── java/
                    ├── module-info.java
                    └── pl/
                        └── edu/
                            └── prz/
                                └── klopusz/
                                    └── utilities/
                                        └── decorators
                                          └──StateMachineDecorator.java
```

The contents of `module-info.java` files is the following:

**org.ggp.base/src/main/java/module-info.java**

```
module org.ggp.base {
    requires guava;
    requires reflections;
    requires jdk.httpserver;

    uses org.ggp.base.util.statemachine.StateMachine;

    exports org.ggp.base;
}
```

**pl.edu.prz.klopusz/dolar-app/src/main/java/module-info.java**

```
module pl.edu.prz.klopusz {
    requires org.ggp.base;

    provides org.ggp.base.util.statemachine.StateMachine
        with pl.edu.prz.klopusz.utilities.decorators.StateMachineDecorator;
}
```

### Compilation

I try to compile the project, using the following command:

```
javac -d out \
  --module-source-path org.ggp.base/src/main/java:pl.edu.prz.klopusz/dolar-app/src/main/java \
  $(find org.ggp.base/src/main/java -name *.java) \
  $(find pl.edu.prz.klopusz/dolar-app/src/main/java -name *.java)
```

#### Errors

I get the following error:

> org.ggp.base/src/main/java/module-info.java:1:
>
> ```
> error: module not found on module source path
> ```
>
> module org.ggp.base {

And 99 other errors for the classes inside `org.ggp.base` package, each is like:

> org.ggp.base/src/main/java/external/JSON/JSONObject.java:1:
>
> ```
> error: not in a module on the module source path
> ```
>
> package external.JSON;

or

> org.ggp.base/src/main/java/org/ggp/base/validator/OPNFValidator.java:1:
>
> ```
> error: not in a module on the module source path
> ```
>
> package org.ggp.base.validator;

### What I want

I want to get rid of the errors and compile the project. I don't have to preserve the directory structure, but when I put it all together, with 2 `module-info.java` files, the compiler complainted about multiple modules. I can have it done by IntelliJ IDEA, I don't mind and I tried. But I don't know what is happening behind the scenes, and I don't know how to handle the errors either (`Package is empty: org.ggp.base`).

[image: Package is empty: org.ggp.base]

### What I've already found

It was hard to find a documentation about `--module-source-path` switch in `javac` command. [This site is what I found](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jigsaw-dev/2016-October/009761.html). It says:

> if you arrange the code in your 
> modules such that you put the code for a module in an enclosing 
> directory named for the module, the module source path becomes more like 
> a simple path, as in
>
> ```
> --module-source-path Users/Me/MyProject/src
> ```
>
> or if it is in multiple projects, use
>
> ```
>     --module-source-path 
>         /Users/Me/MyProject/src:/Users/Me/MyOtherProject/src
> ```

And for Windows use backslashes and semicolons, but I'm using Linux anyway.

There is also a comment to an issue [on OpenJDK bugs site](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8150040?focusedCommentId=14016882&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14016882), with the same error as mine, but I guess it remains unsolved.

*UPDATE*

#### `-verbose` switch

I added `-verbose` switch at the end of command. That is a part of what compiler says:

```
[parsing started SimpleFileObject[/home/sensitive/org.ggp.base/src/main/java/module-info.java]]
[parsing started SimpleFileObject[/home/sensitive/org.ggp.base/src/main/java/org/ggp/base/util/statemachine/MachineState.java]]
[parsing started SimpleFileObject[/home/sensitive/pl.edu.prz.klopusz/dolar-app/src/main/java/module-info.java]]
[parsing started SimpleFileObject[/home/sensitive/pl.edu.prz.klopusz/dolar-app/src/main/java/pl/edu/prz/klopusz/utilities/decorators/StateMachineDecorator.java]]
org.ggp.base/src/main/java/org/ggp/base/util/statemachine/MachineState.java:1: error: not in a module on the module source path
package org.ggp.base.util.statemachine;
^
[loading /modules/jdk.httpserver/module-info.class]
[loading /modules/java.base/module-info.class]
[total 263ms]
100 errors
```

So, I think this is not a fault of the path in `--module-source-path` switch (the same behavior happens with `*src/main/java` pointed out by @StephanHerrmann). It reads all the java sources it should read. There's no problem with sources in the `pl.edu.prz.klopusz` module.
These are the first lines of `org.ggp.base.util.statemachine.MachineState`:

```
package org.ggp.base.util.statemachine;

import org.ggp.base.util.gdl.grammar.GdlSentence;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class MachineState {
    //...
}
```

Comment: I think `--module-source-path` want to find directories named like the modules at first level. OTOH, if I understand JEP 261 correctly, you could perhaps use a pattern like `*/src/main/java` where `*` would represent the module name. I haven't tried this, though.

Comment: @StephanHerrmann, it doesn't matter if I use `*/src/main/java` or `org.ggp.base/src/main/java:pl.edu.prz.klopusz/dolar-app/src/main/java`.

Comment: your directory layout doesn't exactly fit to the `*/src/main/java` pattern, because of the extra `dolar-app` intermediate directory, which prevents matching to the module name.

Comment: After I removed `dolar-app` folder and spliced  `pl.edu.prz.klopusz` and `src`, I used pattern `'./*/src/main/java'`. Neither `*/src/main/java` nor `'*/src/main/java'` nor `org.ggp.base/src/main/java:pl.edu.prz.klopusz/src/main/java` worked. After I used the right pattern, errors disappeared. So I guess you can make an answer out of it and I will accept it.

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't say what's the exact `javac` command should look like, neither do you. For completeness sake, it is `javac -d out --module-source-path "./*/src/main/java/" $(find . -name "*.java")`, right?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar almost. For some reason, I have to use `$(find org.ggp.base/src/main/java -name *.java) $(find pl.edu.prz.klopusz/src/main/java -name *.java)`, because simple search in current dir `find .` doesn't work. I will add it to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21296807.

Comment: I don't understand why the `find` like I showed won't simply work; it has nothing to do with `javac`. I think you're doing something wrong with the `find`.
Your edit was rejected for a different reason, I'll post my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As per [JEP 261](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261) the `--module-source-path` option (for compilation in "multi-module mode") must point to a directory that holds one subdirectory for each contained module, where the directory name must equal the module name.

To accommodate layouts where sources are not directly contained in the module directory, the option supports *patterns* where the token `*` can be used to represent the module name in any part of the path such as in `"./*/src/main/java/"`, which will find the module `my.mod1` in `./my.mod1/src/main/java/module-info.java`  etc.

JEP 261 does not mention any contraints on where in the pattern `*` may occur, but apparently `javac` doesn't like patterns *starting* with `*`. This may or may not be intentional.

Slightly related, I might add that in a previous discussion I was informed that JEP 261 contains outdated information, but my question whether and where this specification would be maintained after the JEP was completed, produced no answer. The [javac manual entry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/tools/javac.htm) is not the place that gives sufficient details for options like `--module-source-path`.

Answer (score 8):

For completeness sake, the complete `javac` command is as follows:

```
javac -d out --module-source-path "./*/src/main/java/" $(find . -name "*.java")
```

Based on the [official tutorial](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start) from OpenJDK (slightly modified directory structure shown below), and OpenJDK version "11.0.1", the above command `javac` works for me:

```
.
├── com.greetings
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── java
│               ├── com
│               │   └── greetings
│               │       └── Main.java
│               └── module-info.java
├── org.astro
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── java
│               ├── module-info.java
│               └── org
│                   └── astro
│                       └── World.java
├── out
│   ├── classes
│   │   ├── com.greetings
│   │   │   ├── com
│   │   │   │   └── greetings
│   │   │   │       └── Main.class
│   │   │   └── module-info.class
│   │   └── org.astro
│   │       ├── module-info.class
│   │       └── org
│   │           └── astro
│   │               └── World.class
│   └── lib
│       ├── com.greetings.jar
│       └── org.astro@1.0.jar
```

Comment: Do you know how to write `javac -d out --module-source-path "./*/src/main/java/" $(find . -name "*.java")` using Windows not Linux/Mac OS ?

Comment: @invzbl3 I believe powershell might provide a more useful set of command line utilities that mimic the Unix find command. Otherwise, you can certainly install a bash (or other) shell into windows. I think Cygwin is the general/GNU implementation, though I simply use the toolkit and shell provided by the git tools for windows. That bash shell (which I suspect is cygwin anyway) works just fine and has "find" and most of the other tools. Learn bash, you'll never look back :)

Comment: It's an old question but just in case anyone stumbles upon this:

You should be able to do in Windows cmd:
dir /s /b *.java > mySourceFiles.txt & javac -d out --module-source-path ".\*\src\main\java\" @sourceFiles.txt &del mySourceFiles.txt

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be more explicit about the module source paths (in some cases where you cannot specify a pattern in regex), there is a module specific form for --module-source-path flag as documented in https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/javac.html#module-specific-form.

```
javac -d out -m org.ggp.base,pl.edu.prz.klopusz --module-source-path org.ggp.base=org.ggp.base/src/main/java --module-source-path pl.edu.prz.klopusz=pl.edu.prz.klopusz/dolar-app/src/main/java
```