# module Directory or module file inside name should be same or not

Tags: java, java-9, java-module, module-info, module-path

**Directory Structure**

```
.
├── out
│   └── calc-module
│       ├── com
│       │   └── ngsharma
│       │       └── ocp
│       │           └── Calculator.class
│       └── module-info.class
└── src
    └── calculator
        ├── com
        │   └── ngsharma
        │       └── ocp
        │           └── Calculator.java
        └── module-info.java
```

**Successfully compile** and generate the **out/calc-module** directory.

```
javac -d out/calc-module src/calculator/module-info.java src/calculator/com/ngsharma/ocp/Calculator.java
```

---

**module-info.java**

```
module calc {}
```

---

**Calculator.java**

```
package com.ngsharma.ocp;

public class Calculator {

    public static int add(int i1, int i2) { return i1 + i2; }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(add(20,40));
    }
}
```

When i compile this module  in following command. 
**1.** java -p out --add-modules calc-module com.ngsharma.ocp.Calculator
When i'm using this command, it throw exception **FindException**: Module **calc-module** not found. 
According to 1. module inside name and module directory name should be same other throw FindException. 
**2** java -p out --add-modules calc com.ngsharma.ocp.Calculator 
but in this situation i'm not using module directory name i'm using only **module-info.java** inside file name, and successfully run. How..? and Why..? 
 module file name and module folder name should be same, otherwise not compile and run it is corrent or not.Please anybody suggest me and correct me what is my mistake.(newbie in module).

Comment: *"According to java Doc module file name and module folder name should be same"*, do share a reference for your quote.

Comment: "According to" what? This sentence is not making sense.. Apart from that "module file name" is always `module-info.java` (and `module-info.class`).

Answer (score 1):

This (first of your commands) doesn't work because there is **no module** named `calc-module`. The name of the module is **`calc`** as specified in the `module-info.java`

```
java -p out --add-modules calc-module com.ngsharma.ocp.Calculator <-- cannot work
```

Either of these two will work for you:

```
java -p out --add-modules calc com.ngsharma.ocp.Calculator
java -p out --module calc/com.ngsharma.ocp.Calculator
```

---

### Compiling

#### Immediate parent directory

There is a way to *compile* modules easily **if** the directory name of the contained module is **identical** to the module name. As in this structure:

```
.
+-- src
    +-- calc
        +-- com
        ¦   +-- ngsharma
        ¦       +-- ocp
        ¦           +-- Calculator.java
        +-- module-info.java
```

Now the entire module can be compiled using:

```
javac -d out --module-source-path src -m calc
```

The **out** directory structure will *automatically* have the name of the module, and hence be identical to the src structure.

This command will not work if the directory name is **not identical** to the module name, and in such case you will get `error: module calc not found in module source path`.

There is no difference in how the program is run. This is **only** valid for compilation.

#### Not immediate parent directory

The use of `--module-source-path` doesn't require that the directory name **identical** to the module name is the immediate parent directory to your package though. You can also create this common structure, where the module name is at the root several directories up:

```
.
+-- calc
    +-- src
        +-- main
            +-- java
                 +-- com
                 ¦    +-- ngsharma
                 ¦        +-- ocp
                 ¦            +-- Calculator.java
                 +-- module-info.java
```

However you need to tweek the compile command is this case (as [Stephan Herrmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4611488) explains in an [answer to "Java 9 error: not in a module on the module source path"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49544403/12695027)):

```
javac -d out --module-source-path "./*/src/main/java/" -m calc
```

---

Note that there is **no requirement** that the directory shares the name with the module itself. It just helps to structure your program and make compiling easier.

Answer (score 0):

The latter command

```
java -p out --add-modules calc com.ngsharma.ocp.Calculator
```

works since the `--add-modules` accepts as argument the name of modules present on the *modulepath* (`out` directory) which in this case is `calc` and not the name of the folder within which the `module-info.java` resides.

To answer the question directly, there is no mandate to name the directory where you build the module same as the module name.